# Permutation testing with LME models

Tags: r, mixed-model, permutation-test

I need to compare two groups of participants to each other in a model that contains fixed and random effects in R. It was suggested to me that a non-parametric test might be ideal for these comparisons. Here is the data:

```r
structure(list(item = c("'accordion_1'", "'accordion_3'", "'apple_01'", 
"'apple_03'", "'asian_01'", "'asian_02'"), avg = c(3.177631579, 
2.868421053, 4.421052632, 4.526315789, 4.440789474, 4.0625), 
    subcat = c("c", "c", "g", "g", "h", "h"), cat = c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group_num = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), group_name = c("adu", 
    "adu", "adu", "adu", "adu", "adu")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I have scoured the internet for code to accomplish this (I am new to both these methods). I initially started by using `perm.lmer()` in the `permutes` package with this code:

```r
asd_kid_mod <- perm.lmer(avg ~ group_name * cat + (1|item), 
    data = asd_kid, nperm = 1000, type = "anova")
```

but it returned p values at 0 which seems strange to me. I also am not sure if mean permutation testing would simply be more appropriate for my data. So I guess my questions are:

1. What is the best method for permutation testing for LMMs in R?
2. Would it make more sense to use mean permutation testing?

EDIT:
Here is my output form `summary`:

```r
         Factor df       LRT          F  p
1    (Intercept)  1 555.54630 253.445582 NA
2     group_name  1  29.48206   1.643257  0
3            cat  1 220.76503  24.153896  0
4 group_name:cat  1  64.43601   4.027463  0
```

and here's a link to what I mean by mean permutation testing: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-permutation-tests-bacc79f45749

I believe it would be using means instead of medians based on the link above

Comment: Why do you want to use permutation testing to compare the two groups? As is, the question doesn't make it clear what data you have and what question you are trying to answer (just that you want to use a permutation test to do it). I would start by providing this context first.